# How can I make my delphi application use FTPS instead of FTP (indy)

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-xe3, ftps

Here's my program:

```
Application.FTP.Host:= vHost;
Application.FTP.Port:= vPort;
try
  Application.FTP.AutoLogin := false;
  Application.FTP.Connect;
  Application.FTP.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize := 2048;
```

I'm using `TIdFTP` component in Delphi XE3.

I think I have to use something like this...

```
 Application.FTP.UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
```

but the compiler doesn't like that line

How can I get my FTP application to use FTPS ?

Comment: What versions of Delphi and Indy?

Answer (score 8):

First, do you need **SFTP** (FTP over SSH) or **FTPS** (FTP over SSL)?  They are not the same thing.  Indy does not support SSH at this time.  For SSL, you can attach an SSL IOHandler, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, to the `TIdFTP.IOHandler` property and then set the `TIdFTP.UseTLS` property to anything other than `utNoTLSSupport` (yes, `TIdFTP` does have a `UseTLS` property).  If you need to encrypt the actual file transfer connections, not just the command connection, then set the `TIdFTP.DataPortProtection` property to `ftpdpsPrivate`.

Answer (score 3):

With Indy10 you can add an TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component and set FTP.IOHandler to point to this component.

And then in TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL you set your SSL options.

Ex.

```
ftpC.IOHandler:=iohFTPSE; //TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL 
ftpC.UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;
ftpC.DataPortProtection:=ftpdpsPrivate;
```

Comment: And you need to set this before `FTP.Connect`

Comment: `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

      Application.FTP.IOHandler:=IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1; //TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
      Application.FTP.UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;
      Application.FTP.DataPortProtection:=ftpdpsPrivate;`

Comment: i got this error: [dcc32 Error] untOpenCommand.pas(103): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'utUseExplicitTLS'

Comment: Add `IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase` unit to your uses clause.

Comment: that worked but i got this one now: [dcc32 Error] untOpenCommand.pas(104): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ftpdpsPrivate'

Comment: fixed it with IdFTPCommon in the uses